# Passing conflicting parameters in gradle - which one will be used?

Tags: gradle

Let's say we are trying to run gradle task with some additional parameters.
For example:

```
./gradlew -Pfeature=true -Pfeature=false
```

Which one of those properties will be passed to build?

Answer (score 0):

I made an experiment using simple gradle task

```
task printProps {
    doLast {
        println props
    }
}
```

I've run it twice:

`./gradlew printProps -Pprops=false -Pprops=true` -> true

`./gradlew printProps -Pprops=true  -Pprops=false` -> false

So gradle uses the last parameter passed.